# mongodb change streams - pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying out change streams using pymongo to check for an update in my collection. It works and returns the updated collection.

```
pipeline = [{
    '$match': {'operationType': 'update'},
}
]
```

And output bson is

```
{
  '_id': {
    '_data': '825FE6C622000000012B022C0100296E5A1004731D2D44381F4405B1C7808CE45703F046645F696400645FE58A91DAFF726006C3D1E90004'
  },
  'operationType': 'update',
  'clusterTime': Timestamp(1608959522,
  1),
  'ns': {
    'db': 'iec',
    'coll': 'Substation'
  },
  'documentKey': {
    '_id': ObjectId('5fe58a91daff726006c3d1e9')
  },
  'updateDescription': {
    'updatedFields': {
      'College': [
        {
          'name': 'C1',
          'Student': [
            {
              'name': 'S1',
              'rank': 1

            },
            {
              'name': 'S2',
              'rank': 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    'removedFields': [
      
    ]
  }
}
```

But I dont want those extra fields like operation type, clustertime, so on. I just want College array which as students details.  How to change my pipleline in order to achieve ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add project stage after the match to suppress the fields you need:

```
pipeline = [{ '$match': {'operationType': 'update'}} , {'$project': { 'operationType':0 , _id:0 , 'clusterTime':0    } }]
```

Comment: `{'$project': { '_id': 0 , 'updateDescription.updatedFields.College': 1}}`might be closer.